# How to handle two dispatch Actions on HandleSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, react-redux

I need to dispatch two different action on SubmitForm the Logic is if the first Action succeeds I dispatch the second Action

I did like this

```
const handleClick = () =>{
setLoading(true)
const authorizationCode = refInput.current.state.tan
const email = emailValues?.email;
const UserId = phoneValues?.data?.d;
const phone_number = phoneValues?.value?.phone_number
const language = phoneValues?.value?.language

dispatch(verifyUserNumber({
  email,
  authorizationCode ,
  language,
  UserId,
  phone_number,
}))

setTimeout(() => {
  if(isDoneVerifyingUser){
      dispatch(getKycToken(UserId, phone_number, authorizationCode)) 
      setTimeout(() => {
        setOpenModel(false)
        setOpenKYC(true)
        setLoading(false)
        
      }, 2000); 
    }else{
      setError(true)
      setLoading(false)
    }
}, 2000);
```

}

**but I have a problem which is I have to click on the button twice to dispatch the second the action**

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to hard code a time such as 2 seconds to wait before triggering another event. Is it possible to combine the redux state? There is probably a better way to do this, but it's difficult to know what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I don't think in my case it will be possible to do so, because I have to wait until I get the response from the first action I mean I have to wait till `isDoneVerifyingUser === true` , then dispatch the second action
and please lemme know what's the better idea to handle the time out here ? - DCTID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a variable `isDoneVerifying` in state.

After dispatching first action, update state to true or false based on outcome.

In your component use hook `useEffect` which is dependent on `isDoneVerifying` and call the second dispatch. make sure you change flag to false after executing reducer part.